# Removing thermosensitive part of time-series

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression

I have hourly data and I want to extract the non-thermosensitive part of an electric consumption of a building. The external temperature is available.

Given that the electric consumption is highly volatile, I first thought about using dummy variables for each hour, day (weekday or weekend), and month of the year.

Then I "separated" the temperature into 6 categories: Since the thermosensitive part I would like to extract is the result of heating and cooling (mostly), I separated temperatures below 15°C, between 15° and 25°, and above 25°. I also separated the temperatures when the building was occupied or not, since the presence of people can influence the temperature inside.

My question is: Is it possible to remove the thermosensitive part of the series? And if it is, what method should I use?

Comment: I'm having trouble following this. What is the "thermosensible part" of the data? Can you give some simple example numbers that illustrate what you want to do?

Comment: @gung In Romance languages "sensible" means *sensitive.*  Thus we should understand this to be a question about removing the temperature-related effects of electricity consumption from what appears to be a very fine-grained time series.

Comment: So is the idea here that you have energy consumption for a building over time, & you want to estimate how much energy is used to, say, keep the lights on, vs how much is used to run the air conditioning?

Comment: @gung : Yes, this is what I meant to say.

Comment: Since the data appear to be (at least) hourly, heating and cooling degree-days will not be sufficiently granular to do much good.  Ideally, you are trying to estimate (and remove) the *response* of the building HVAC machinery to *outside temperatures* (as well as to other factors like the number of occupants).  That response will be nonlinear and even non-monotonic.  Although many techniques exist to handle such general responses, you might make a good start by choosing functions that are compatible with physical theory, as described at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/148166.

Answer (score 0):

Your thoughts on incorporating deterministic effects like hour-of-the-day ;day-of-the-week ; holidays (pre and post) etc are in the correct direction and is precisely what is needed . I would not separate the temperatures but rather use heating and cooling degree days as two predictors . One way I have seen this work is to approach it with a parent/child relationship i.e. daily/hourly. I just posted a response [What is the frequency in my series and does it matter for my forecasting models (SARIMA)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245791/seasonal-arima-model-from-small-no-s-of-observations) that you might want to review as it focuses on multi-frequency analysis of time series data which is what you have.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are proposing when you say _"I would not separate the temperatures but rather use heating and cooling degree days as two predictors."_ Do you mean adding a different dummy variable?

Comment: Yes .. take a look at  the url that whuber recommended .  Additionally we have used two variables to model temperature , var1 = 0 if temperature >32 and 32-temp otherwise ; var2 =0 and temp-75 otherwise. These two variable capture the "bathtub response" of ten seen when temperature is important.